# Laravel Http::fake ConnectionException

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-http-client

How to test http macro retry counts on Connection failure?

AppServiceProvider:

```
Http::macro('host', function () {
            return Http::acceptJson()
                ->retry(5, 600, function (\Exception $exception, PendingRequest $request) {
                    return $exception instanceof ConnectionException;
                });
        });
```

Feature test:

```
public function test_connection_exception(): void
{
    Http::preventStrayRequests();

    Http::fake([
        '*' => // I need something here...
    ]);

    Http::assertSentCount(5);
}
```

Comment: What is your test outputting?